# How accurate Stopwatch is in long-term?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7

How accurate Stopwatch is in long-term? i.e. how much difference with precise time can grow, when running for several days?

Comment: I think its very much dependent on your hardware OS

Comment: You are better of using DateTime Ticks for this sort of requirement.

Comment: @Lloyd, can you elaborate on why you think that's true. Guessing, but I suspect stop watch uses that or a more accurate mechanism under the hood.

Comment: @kenny from the MSDN reference library. "On a multiprocessor computer, it does not matter which processor the thread runs on. However, because of bugs in the BIOS or the Hardware Abstraction Layer (HAL), you can get different timing results on different processors".

Answer (score 0):

As @V4Vendetta mentioned, it is hardware/OS dependent.

What you should be interested in when using the stopwatch to measure a particular task is the delta or difference between timings.

Comment: I need to measure difference in time. But this difference can be as high as several days. Particularly, I don't want to use DateTime.Now due to time adjustment effects, etc.